# How to resolve nonetype object has no attribute encode error in python 2.7

Tags: python, xml, unicode

I was running the following code:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('dblp_16.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
f = open('hi', 'w')
for country in root.findall('article'):
    rank = country.find('year').text
    name = country.find('title')

    if(int(rank)>2009):
        f.write(name.text.encode('utf8'))
        f.write(':')
        auth = country.findall('author')
        for a in auth:
            #print str(a)
            f.write(a.text.encode('utf8'))  
            f.write(',')
        f.write('\n')
```

An error occured while running the above code:"nonetype object has no attribute encode".How to resolve it?

Comment: *"How to resolve it?"* - By not calling `encode()` on `None`. Look at your XML and think where this might happen.

Comment: One of `name.text` or `a.text` is *empty* or doesn't contain *just* a text node, so `None` is returned instead. `None` doesn't have a `.encode()` method.

Comment: @MartijnPieters:How can i solve that?

Comment: @MartijnPieters:Actually it is shown in command prompt that name.text part is having error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply check `if name.text is not None`

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('dblp_16.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
f = open('hi', 'w')
for country in root.findall('article'):
    rank = country.find('year').text
    name = country.find('title')
    if not name.text:
        continue
    if(int(rank)>2009):
        f.write(name.text.encode('utf8'))
        f.write(':')
        auth = country.findall('author')
        for a in auth:
            #print str(a)
            f.write(a.text.encode('utf8'))  
            f.write(',')
        f.write('\n')
```

Comment: No problem, next time try to be more specified with your question :)